# blackberry.pim.calendar not working for me

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I just started writing a app for BB10, and playing around with the calendarEvent object.

```
function createEvents(location, summary, startTime, endTime, frequency, dayInWeek, expires) {

var testing = blackberry.pim.calendar;
document.write("<p>My First app</p>");

var evt,
calendar = blackberry.pim.calendar,
CalendarRepeatRule = calendar.CalendarRepeatRule;
var start = new Date(startTime);
var end = new Date(endTime);
var location = location;
var summary = summary;
.
.
.
}
```

I am running this in ripple, but it wont even print out "My First app" when I run this function.
In my config.xml I have

Been stuck for hours, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blackberry.pim.calendar API is not supported by Ripple:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.pim.calendar.html

I suspect that a runtime error is occurring when you set the **testing** variable inside of createEvents. Open Web inspector to confirm.

Recommend doing feature detection to ensure the object you are about to use is available.

```
    function createEvents(location, summary, startTime, endTime, frequency, dayInWeek, expires) {

   if (window.blackberry && blackberry.pim) {
      var testing = blackberry.pim.calendar;
      document.write("<p>My First app</p>");

      var evt,
         calendar = blackberry.pim.calendar,
         CalendarRepeatRule = calendar.CalendarRepeatRule;
      var start = new Date(startTime);
      var end = new Date(endTime);
      var location = location;
      var summary = summary;
   } else {
      alert("blackberry.pim is not supported");
   }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: yea I think you are right, that was stupid of me, I assumed ripple can run it cause it let me set the platform in bb10. Thanks